# Bootstrap 5 date picker Edge and Chrome not allowing correct dates when days are limited using JS

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am using bootstrap 5.02 and I am trying to allow the user to only select dates that are on either a Tuesday or a Thursday.  I have created a JavaScript listener event, but in Edge and Chrome the page will only allow the user to choose Wednesdays. The strange thing is that when I test this code on Tor (Firefox) the code works as expected, allowing the user to choose a Tuesday or Thursday.

My Javascript is:

```
const dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]');

dateInputs.forEach(dateInput => {
  dateInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const selectedDate = new Date(event.target.value);
    const dayOfWeek = selectedDate.getDay();

    if (dayOfWeek !== 2 && dayOfWeek !== 4) {
      alert('Please select a Tuesday or Thursday.');
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  });
});
```

I tried using change instead of input, but the same result happened.

Full code is available here at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/William-Teale/pen/XWodEoO) - Codepen also does the same thing as Edge and Chrome.

Is this a localized thing on my machine somehow? Or am I missing something?